# rewrite in web form application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, c#-3.0

Recently: converted a website to web application.

On Website version: a folder name called 'ordermanagement' placed in solution level.
So all the urls are locked down with the folder name.

```
EG: ../ordermanagement/....js
    ../ordermanagement/order.aspx
http://domain:63604/Orders.aspx
http://domain:63604/contactus.aspx
```

After converted to web app, i don't use the folder in solution level anymore.
Business people wants to keep the url which has been used for long time.

```
http://domain:63604/ordermanagement/Orders.aspx
http://domain:63604/ordermanagement/contactus.aspx
```

So, question is how to url rewrite in webform in order to achieve above urls.
Any advice ?

Comment: Maybe URL rewriting [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx] could be a solution?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".